# How to call a WCF service using ksoap2 on android?

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

Here is my code

```
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ksop2test extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */


 private static final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";
// private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
// private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";

 private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.2:8080/HelloWCF/Service1.svc";
// private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.2:8080/webservice1/Service1.asmx";

 final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/SayHello";
// final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
 TextView tv;
 StringBuilder sb;



 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  tv = new TextView(this);
  sb = new StringBuilder();
  call();
  tv.setText(sb.toString());
  setContentView(tv);
 }

 public void call() {
  try {

   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

   request.addProperty("name", "Qing");

   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
     SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
   sb.append(envelope.toString() + "\n");//cannot get the xml request send
   SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

   //to get the data
   String resultData = result.toString();
   // 0 is the first object of data 


   sb.append(resultData + "\n");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   sb.append("Error:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
  }

 }

}
```

I can successfully access .asmx service, but when I try to call a wcf service 
the virtual machine said :
Error:
expected:END_TAG{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body(position:END_TAGhttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Fault>@1:712 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43ba6798

How to print what the request send?

Here is the wcf wsdl:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">

<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://para-bj.para.local:8080/HelloWCF/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://para-bj.para.local:8080/HelloWCF/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="IService1_SayHello_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SayHello"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="IService1_SayHello_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="IService1">
  <wsdl:operation name="SayHello">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SayHello" message="tns:IService1_SayHello_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SayHelloResponse" message="tns:IService1_SayHello_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" type="tns:IService1">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

  <wsdl:operation name="SayHello">
   <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/SayHello" style="document"/>

     <wsdl:input>
       <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:input> 
     <wsdl:output>
       <soap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="Service1">

  <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
    <soap:address location="http://para-bj.para.local:8080/HelloWCF/Service1.svc"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

It uses `<xsd:schema>` in tag `<wsdl:types>`
and the asmx uses `<s:schema>` in tag `<wsdl:types>`
what's the difference?

Comment: You probably can't use ksoap, as the davalik JVM is not the same as the Sun JVM.  You may need to write your own SOAP parser.  SOAP is really too heavy for a mobile device, IMO.

Comment: But I can successfully get data from a .asmx service

Answer (score 19, accepted):

finally I got it to work
because the namespace missed a "/" in the end ,

following is my code

```
package cn.qing.ksop2test;


import java.io.Writer;

import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ksop2test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorldRequest";
//  private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
//  private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";

private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.2:8080/HelloWCF/Service1.svc";
//  private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.2:8080/webservice1  /Service1.asmx";

final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/HelloWorld";
//  final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
TextView tv;
StringBuilder sb;
private XmlSerializer writer;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    call();
    tv.setText(sb.toString());
    setContentView(tv);
}

public void call() {
    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("Name", "Qing");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

        //to get the data
        String resultData = result.toString();
        // 0 is the first object of data 


        sb.append(resultData + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        sb.append("Error:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is very good demo code for access the WCF webservice in android app..........., I have apply this source code and resolve my issues .....

Comment: The thing for me is there is a different response type depending on what the method returns. If there is one return value you use a SoapPrimitive type, if there is a more complex type you use a SoapObject.

Comment: you have no idea how much this have helped me. thanks heaps. I missed that "/" character as well. :D

Comment: Hello. I used your code a long time ago. Today my app has been banned from Google Play because it was using "tempuri.org". Do you know why is tempuri.org needed? I am trying to remove it from your code but then it stops working. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IContact/GetContactCount";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetContactCount";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.com/Contacts/ContactsService.Contacts.svc";
```

So maybe the problem is in your SOAP action.

Also is the spelling on your method name correct ie AuthenticatdUser?

Answer (score 0):

In "theory" wcf with basic http binding and asmx should work the same.

It could be something to do with how your WCF service is configured.

We get a similar problem if we configure TransferMode Streamed on the client and Buffered on the server. Although not sure if this is relevant in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Qing for your answer it's really help full for calling WCF service

I would like to add this rectification for getting simple and complex output from web service after setting outputSoapObject into envelope,please correct me if i'm wrong

```
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestSoapObject);

        // if its dotnet web service then make it true
        if (isDotNetWebService)
            envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + methodName, envelope);

        if (useBodyIn) // use bodyIn if service method returns string/int
                        // etc
        {
            /* Gives output from webservice */
            responseSoapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        } else // use getResponse() if service method returns objects or
                // array
        {
            /* Gives output from webservice */
            responseSoapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        }
```