# How to use WCF in Android

Tags: android, wcf, wcf-client

I provide a remote tool to other websites through web service in WCF.
Now I want to provide same remote tool to Android Apps.
My question is:
Can Android apps consume my WCF web services (hosted on webserver) or do I need to change something.

Comment: If Android has a HTTP stack, and your WCF service is using the `webHttpBinding` - yes, sure! Your client just needs to navigate to some predefined URLs using HTTP - that's all

Answer (score 3):

You have WCF service and you want to consume it from Android application. First of all your service must be interoperable. In case of Android client you should use either `basicHttpBinding` (SOAP service) or `webHttpBinding` (REST service).

- To consume SOAP service use [kSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589486/how-to-call-a-wcf-service-using-ksoap2-on-android) is some description how to call the service
- To consume REST service use use [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and call the serivice as any other HTTP resource (for REST service it is better to use JSON as a transport format) - [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service) is some example.