# WCF seems ignore web.config and gives 413: Entity too large

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF web services which keep giving me a 413 response when I post a large JSON request to it, I have added the maximum limit into the web.config but it seems they are ignored, I would like to know is there anything wrong in my web.config?

Here is my web.config

```html
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="myService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/myService" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="myBinding" name="myService"
          contract="ImyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks!

EDITED:

I have "solved" the problem, by adding a new binding with name = "", which overwrite the default binding setting, and everything goes fine.

Being said, **myBinding** is actually being ignored or not bound to my service endpoint...
Can anyone figuring out the reason behind??

Comment: [Try this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7e0d74d3-ca01-4d36-8ac7-6b2ca03fd383.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Tried, still not working...

Comment: Do both your client and server binding configs match?

Comment: I was posting request via Fiddler, and ultimately the client is a mobile client android application, I assume there is no need to set any config on the client side....am I wrong?

Comment: See if either of these help?
http://www.allenconway.net/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483053/how-to-use-wcf-in-android