# c# wcf service how to consume call java client

Tags: wcf, java-client

**../Iservice1.cs/**

```
public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Int32 Add(Int32 Num1, Int32 Num2);
}
```

**../Iservice1.svc.cs/**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Int32 Add(Int32 Num1, Int32 Num2)
        {
            return Num1 + Num2;
        }
}
```

I created the service. I opened a project in Javada and added the service. But how can I call the service in java "add" method.?
**SOLVE:**

```
public class JavaApplication {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathService service = new MathService();
        IMathService serv;
        serv = service.getBasicHttpBindingIMathService();
        int x=8, y=2;
        int ans;
        ans=serv.add(x, y);
        System.out.println(ans);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the IntelliJ IDEA as an example.
In Java, there is a `webservice` client library. It could help us generate the client java code, then we use the client to call the service.
[image]
It prompts us to input the `WSDL` page when the project is opened, WCF usually publish the complete `WSDL` file by `SingleWSDL` instead of `WSDL` page. The `SingleWSDL` contains all service definitions in one file. Here we input `SingleWSDL` URL.
[image]
We could also take advantage of Tools Menu to add the Webservice client java code.
[image]
The `ServiceLocator` class includes our client java code. We can use automatically generated `HelloWolrdClient.java` to simulate the invocation, Press `Alt+enter` to import the jar package.
[image]
At last, please do not forget to modify the service URL, the default is `localhost`.
 [image]
Run the Main method in `HelloWorldClient`. Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: how to wcf web service call android studio?

Comment: I don't know much about the Andriod application. KSOAP2 library seems a good solution to this problem.  http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/getting-started.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589486/how-to-call-a-wcf-service-using-ksoap2-on-android